# Concatenate two fields in a ListView ng-admin

Tags: ng-admin

I have a listview with a few fields, two of the fields are firstName, lastName. I would like to display Name as a header and concatenate firstName and lastName.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet to do so:

```
var user = nga.entity('Users');
user.listView()
      .fields([
          nga.field('id').label('Name').map(function (value, entry) {
              return entry.firstName + ' ' + entry.lastName;
          })
      ]);
```